# BLE (blue tooth low energy) : what is the max length of a packet? (encrypted and unencrypted)

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

According to BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION:
"The Length field of the Header indicates the length of the Payload and MIC if
included. The length field has the range of 0 to 255 octets. The Payload field
shall be less than or equal to 251 octets in length. The MIC is 4 octets in length."

Thus, what is not clear for me is : **What is the max payload size?**

it could be wether:

1) 251 for both

- max payload size is 251 for both encrypted and unecrypted packet
- max length for encrypted packet is max size + 4 (MIC) => 255
- max length for unencrypted packet is max size : 251

2) 251 / 255

- max payload size is 251 for encrypted packet, max length is 251 + 4 (MIC) => 255,
- max payload size is 255 for unencrypted packet, max length is 255

User cannot send a unencrypted packet with a size > 255 because length field is a byte. So, when encryption is not enabled, there is nothing to do, buffer overflow is avoided by design.

But, I guess when coding an LL BLE API, we should check before sending a packet if its size is > 251, and warn user if necessary.
(case 1 for unencrypted and encrypted packets, case 2 for encrypted packet)

Comment: "The Payload field shall be less than or equal to 251 octets in length".

Comment: There are different payloads at different layers. See equivalent question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913743